# Three20: Facebook-like Zoom In animation?

Tags: animation, three20, launcher

I wanna have a ZoomIn / ZoomOut Animation for my Three20 Launcher.

Anybody any idea?

Answer (score 0):

i made sample three20 project few weeks with expanding launcher effect. feel free to download:

https://github.com/aporat/TTLauncherView_ExpandViewTransitions